# React Toaster not working before redirecting to another page using useHistory()

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-hooks

I am using react toaster to pop up a message and then immediately want to redirect to another page using
history.push('/') 
 But the toaster does not work and the page redirects immediately to homepage.
I want toaster to popup first and then the page should redirect to homepage. My toaster code is correct as it works well when I don't use history.push();

```
toast.success('Regitered !', {
position:'top-center'
autoClose:5000
})

history.push('/');
```

Comment: have you tried using `await`?

Comment: Hi @ritik_jain, 
Please mark this answer as accepted if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use onClose method like below

```
   toast.success('Regitered !', {
       position:'top-center'
       autoClose:5000,
       onClose: () => history.push('/')
    });
```

Or render the ToastContainer at the root of your app index.js or App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ToastContainer position="top-center" theme="colored" autoClose={2000} />
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);


reportWebVitals();
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have to use a promise to handle this history.push which is getting executed first, please take reference from below code block:

```
handleSubmit = (user) => {
 saveUser(user).then(() =>
 this.props.history.push('/dashboard')
 )).catch((error) => {
  console.log("error", error);
  this.setState({
    finishedStep: false,
  });
  this.props.history.push("/Sample");
 })
}
```

Comment: Hi Ritik, 
Please mark this answer as accepted if it solves your problem